# Regex question using sublime (Find/Replace)

Tags: regex, replace, find

Ok, using either bash terminal or find/replace in something like sublime, I want to find:

```
BLK=$'\e[0;30m'
RED=$'\e[0;31m'
GRN=$'\e[0;32m'
YEL=$'\e[0;33m'
BLU=$'\e[0;34m'
MAG=$'\e[0;35m'
CYN=$'\e[0;36m'
WHT=$'\e[0;37m'
```

The first 3 letters, and the =$, and replqace it with the first 3 alias those first 3 letters="echo -e (everything after the quotation and before the last quotation). So far, not even this:

Here is where I get stuck:

I can find/replace the with alias (first 3 letters) but can't finish the rest. That regex looks like so:

```
Find: ([A-Z]{3,5})(\=\$)(?:\')(\\e\[\d\;?\d{1,3}m)(?:\')
Replace: alias  \1
```

But can't seem to finish the whole thing. Using sublime text editor.

Comment: Why the `perl` tag?

Comment: Removed `perl` tag since the question has nothing at all to do with that language.  Please see which "_sublime_"-related tags would be appropriate and add those instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using Sublime, you could use 2 capture groups instead adding the `=` to the first capture group and the closing `'` to the second capture group as you want to keep those.

You could find:

```
([A-Z]{3,5}=)\$'(\\e\[\d\;?\d{1,3}m')
```

And replace with:

```
alias $1'echo -e $2
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PzRO4s/1)

Note that you do not have to escape the quote and you can omit the non capture group, so `(?:\')` will be just `'`

Answer (score 0):

It may be with the replacement string; the pattern was correct. (I am familiar with only Java and posting a working solution here. Please see if it helps you to create an equivalent Sublime replacement.)

```java
String s = "BLK=$'\\e[0;30m'\nRED=$'\\e[0;31m'\nGRN=$'\\e[0;32m'";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "([A-Z]{3,5})(\\=\\$)(?:\\')(\\\\e\\[\\d\\;?\\d{1,3}m)(?:\\')" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( input );

while( m.find() ){
    String repl = m.replaceAll( "alias $1='echo -e $3'" );
    System.out.println( repl );
}
```

In case you aren't familiar with Java:

- The pattern may seem confusing due to the many `\` escape characters. But I have used exactly the same pattern as you posted, which is `([A-Z]{3,5})(\=\$)(?:\')(\\e\[\d\;?\d{1,3}m)(?:\')`.
- In Java, the groups are identified as `$1`, `$2`, etc. instead of `\1`, `\2`, etc.

**Result**

For the `input` value in the code, which I took from your question, the following is the output:

```
alias BLK='echo -e \e[0;30m'
alias RED='echo -e \e[0;31m'
alias GRN='echo -e \e[0;32m'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following *capture pattern*.

```
(.+?)=\$'(.+?)'
```

And, the following replacement text.

```
alias $1='echo -e $2'
```

Output

```
alias BLK='echo -e \e[0;30m'
alias RED='echo -e \e[0;31m'
alias GRN='echo -e \e[0;32m'
alias YEL='echo -e \e[0;33m'
alias BLU='echo -e \e[0;34m'
alias MAG='echo -e \e[0;35m'
alias CYN='echo -e \e[0;36m'
alias WHT='echo -e \e[0;37m'
```